# redirecting a .Net application to bypass strong named GAC dlls and use local versions instead

Tags: .net, strongname

I have a .Net WinForms application which uses signed .Net dlls from the GAC. I need to replace these GAC dlls with newer versions.

The problem I have, is that the WinForms application cannot be re-compiled. We don't have the code anymore.

We'll be re-writing it in the near future. However, in the meantime, I MUST replace these dlls (other, newer apps depend on these new versions), and I MUST have this older application still running.

Is there a way (via manifest or something like that) to force this one application to use local dlls, so that I can extract its old dependencies from the GAC and place them in the application's folder? I looked into the many similar questions, and they all said you must re-compile the application to use versions that are not strong-named.

Alternatively, is there a way to take the compiled application and change the IL code to reference non-strong-named dlls and THEN use the local versions?

Comment: what if you unregister the previous version from GAC and register the new one with the same name?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK - I haven't tested this, but from what I understand, if I add in new dlls with the same name, then when the app loads up it will try and load the new ones from the GAC. Currently, my only option is to rename all my dlls so that the new apps can use them and the old app can use its old dlls, and I don't want to do that.

Comment: Ohh... in that case, you will need the source code to direct the application which dll to read! :(